# Android Studio 3.0.1 Won't build NDK static library

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0, android.mk

I'm trying to build and include a static library in my Android Studio project. My project builds and runs fine without the static library.

My top-level **Android.mk** includes 2 explicit **SQLite.mk** and **Hello.mk** lines.

I have specified full paths in all of these .mk files just for my own sanity.

SQLite.mk is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

JNILIB_PATH := C:/androidprojects/SDLTest_SQLite/app/jniLibs 

SRC_SQLITE := C:/androidprojects/SDLTest_SQLite/app/jni/SQLite/sqlite3.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-write-strings

LOCAL_MODULE    := SQLite
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC_SQLITE)

TARGET_OUT=$(JNILIB_PATH)/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
#TARGET_OUT=../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Android Studio/Gradle error is as follows:

```
Android NDK: ERROR:C:\androidprojects\SDLTest_SQLite\app\jni\Android.mk:SQLite: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that C:/androidprojects/SDLTest_SQLite/app/jniLibs/armeabi/libSQLite.a exists  or that its path is correct   
Build command failed.
```

My fundamental problem is that I cannot get a **libSQLite.a** file to be generated anywhere. Is my `TARGET_OUT` line the problem?

Can somebody please help me generate my static library file?

[Here is a link to my project](http://www.mediafire.com/file/twd21uca1uhgc6p/androidprojects.zip)

Comment: Next time, please put your code on GitHub or similar; it's pain to work with zip from mediafire, especially from the mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set `TARGET_OUT` in **Android.mk**: this is a sure way to break the subtle **ndk-build** logic. Your two **mk** files contradict one another: SQLite cannot be both prebuilt and built from sources.

I don't know why your error message says that the SQLite source is missing, but you use full paths which is unhealthy.

Here are the three **mk** files that do their job:

**Android.mk**

```
ROOT_PATH   := $(call my-dir)

include $(ROOT_PATH)/src/Hello.mk
include $(ROOT_PATH)/SQLite/SQLite.mk
```

**SQLite.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SRC_SQLITE := sqlite3.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-write-strings

LOCAL_MODULE    := SQLite
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC_SQLITE)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

**Hello.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libSDL2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../jniLibs/SDL2-prebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libSDL2.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../jniLibs/SDL2-prebuilt

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SDL_PATH)/include

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 52_hello_mobile.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libSDL2 SQLite
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The latter can be slightly improved even more:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libSDL2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../jniLibs/SDL2-prebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libSDL2.so
SDL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../jniLibs/SDL2-prebuilt
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(SDL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 52_hello_mobile.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libSDL2 SQLite
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

One more fox to your setup: you cannot build 64-bit versions with `APP_PLATFORM=14`. You should use **compileSdkVersion** at least **21**, and don't set `APP_PLATFORM` explicitly. Then, gradle will automatically set `APP_PLATFORM` according to **minSdkVersion** for 32-bit targets (i.e. `android-14`), and push it to `android-21` for 64-bit targets.

In **Aplication.mk**, `APP_PLATFORM` setting is silently ignored.

Comment: This line confuses me: LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libSDL2 SQLite  What does "SQLite" in this line actually do? I see you removed the lines which I thought told Hello.mk what libSQLite was. Does this line now refer to the "LOCAL_MODULE" line of SQLite.mk? It it does, it looks a lot neater.

Comment: Exactly. Module names are global.

Comment: If I remove the "include $(ROOT_PATH)/src/Hello.mk" line from the top level Android.mk, the libSQLite.a isn't compiled or created. What is the reason or dependency for this? There must be something within the Hello.mk file that results in the ultimate building of libSQLite.a Sorry - I am just trying to understand the ndk build system subtleties. It seems very fragile and I break it very easily.

Comment: Static libraries are not "primary targets" for NDK. You can force NDK to build static library alone. Or, if you keep **Hello.mk**, it will be built because a primary target depends on it.

Comment: How would I force NDK to build a static library? I've raised a few other NDK related question on here as I'm struggling to understand the build/compiler dependency behaviour overall.

Comment: Try https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions:targets

Comment: Thanks - the documentation threw me a little. 'targets "SQLite"' worked fine - so I guess you have to use the LOCAL_MODULE name within for 'targets' - i.e. libSQLite.a doesn't work.